# DotNetNuke 7 An error occurred trying to create the site

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I've installed DotNetNuke 7 on my computer and it works perfectly. I managed to install the Christoc extension for visual studio 2010  and it also works perfectly (I watched the video).
The problem is that the extension for vs2010 is outdated and I would like to use it on vs 2012.
So I downloaded the vsix file from codeplex and installed it for vs 2012. The problem is that I get two errors when creating a "DotNetNuke 7 C# DAL2 Compiled Module" in VS 2012.

This is the first one (I don't think it is a blocking one): 
("The project ('DNNVS2012') is configuerd to use the IIS Web server which...")
[image: The project ('DNNVS2012') is configuerd to use the IIS Web server which...]

Then I get a second error:
"An error occurred trying to create the site http://[...] applicationHost.config Error: Cannot write configuration file"
[image: An error occurred trying to create the site http://... applicationHost.config Error: Cannot write configuration file]

And the I get the exception:

[image: ComException]

In the end, the project is not created at all. Does anyone know how to solve this?
I launched unlocker on the applicationHost.config file and it did not find any lock on the file.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have DNN running locally using IIS and DNNDEV.ME as the URL?

You might need to open Visual Studio as Administrator, instead of just opening it without Admin rights, as it needs access to IIS

Comment: DNN run locally using IIS but I don't have DNNDEV.ME as the url. Is it important for the template?
I tried to run vs as an administrator and it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, the template requires DNNDEV.ME as the URL, or you have to change the template/project created from the template. Open up the CSPROJ file in Notepad and search for DNNDEV.ME and change it to your local URL.